# User Authentication not carrying between two ASP.NET Core applications on one IIS Site

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I have two projects that share a user pool.  On my local machine when you log into one project you don't need to log in to the second.  When I publish the project and move it to a server and deploy it using IIS Manager the authentication doesn't carry from the first project to the second.
This chunk of code is from the Startup of one of the projects, the second project has an identical Configure.

Most of the original code wasn't written by me, I've just adapted it to have the second project.  If more information/code is needed, let me know and I can add it.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseBrowserLink();
        string cookieName = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<AppSettings>>().Value.CookieName;
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseResponseCompression();
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = cookieName,
            CookieName = cookieName,
            DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\sharedAuthKeys\"), new X509Certificate2(@"c:\sharedAuthKeys\certificate.p12", password)),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/Forbidden/"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });
```

The current thing I'm looking into is the fact that on the server the user profile is not available, while on my local machine it is.